# How do I map to HashMap for array?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON I want a to convert it to a HashMap. I have the following code -

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, String> jsonData = new HashMap<String, String>();

jsonData = mapper.readValue(userPropertyJson, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,String>>(){});
```

it is working fine if the input JSON is

```
{"user":1, "entity": "email"}
```

but fails when the JSON is as below -

```
{"user":1, "entity": ["email","fname","lname","phone"]}
```

How do I map to HashMap for array also?

Comment: HashMap<String, Object> ??

Comment: You have different types of object as value. So `HashMap<String, Object>` might do.

Comment: Which is a very bad approach anyway. You will end up checking what type is the value for given key etc. Rather than trying to get it to work with Map<String, Object>, I would revisit my model and made it so I know what types I will get in different fields.

Comment: Why do you have such different input? Didn't someone define the format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a generic `HashMap` with `String` as a key  and Object as a value , since you don't know the type of value exactly.

```
Map<String, Object>
```

*And beware of assigning wrong types while retrieving data*

Answer (score 2):

Use `Map<String, Object>`. Example

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


public class JacksonParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userPropertyJson = "{\"user\":1, \"entity\": [\"email\",\"fname\",\"lname\",\"phone\"]}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
        Map<String, Object> jsonData = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        jsonData = mapper.readValue(userPropertyJson, new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){});
        System.out.println(jsonData);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know *in advance* that your json will always have the same format (a `String` key mapped to a `List<String>`, either with a single element or with many elements), then you could use the `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` deserialization feature:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);

String jsonWithArray = 
    "{\"user\": 1, \"entity\": [\"email\", \"fname\", \"lname\", \"phone\"]}";

Map<String, List<String>> map1 = 
    mapper.readValue(
        jsonWithArray,
        new TypeReference<HashMap<String, List<String>>>() {});

System.out.println(map1); // {user=[1], entity=[email, fname, lname, phone]}

String jsonWithoutArray = "{\"user\": 1, \"entity\": \"email\"}";

Map<String, List<String>> map2 = 
    mapper.readValue(
        jsonWithoutArray, 
        new TypeReference<HashMap<String, List<String>>>() {});

System.out.println(map2); // {user=[1], entity=[email]}
```

This enables you to either have an array for the values in your json, or a single element.

Comment: It may not be always `List<String>`  `Map<String, Object>` is working for me.

Comment: @user3306669 `Map<String, Object>` will always work for any JSON object, since it's the most general structure. However, you have to cast the values when you get them out of the map. This is highly error-prone, that's why I took the `ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` approach. According to your question, I thought it was enough to cover all your possible JSONs. Anyways, I'm glad you made it work with `Map<String, Object>`. Just be careful when retrieving values from the map.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

It allows you to convert json to java object automatically. I use it when I need to create DTOs from a web service for which I don't have java mapping or SDK.

Comment: That's good that it worked, but I personally prefer not to deal with Object class as it is not type safe. That's why I suggested that resource so that you can convert your JSON to a more concrete class.

Comment: Actually JSON input can be any type. Depending on the input type some operation will go on.